# Is there a limit to the number of calendar events that can be programmatically scheduled for a given user?

Tags: ruby, google-api, google-calendar-api

My web app has an event scheduling feature, and I'd like to automatically create, update, and delete calendar events from users' individual calendars as the event details change on my site.

My plan to do this is to set up an automated/service user (e.g. `events@example.co`) and use the Calendar API to send invites that come from that user. As the event gets updated I continue to use the API through that user (using a server-to-server authentication protocol, so no human authorization required) to modify the event and deliver updates

If I'm scheduling several thousand events - will this scale with just one user? It doesn't feel right to schedule so many events under one automated user. But then again, it might work just fine.

1. Is there a limit to how many events I can schedule?
2. Is there a more sane way to approach this overall?

Thanks!

Comment: I would argue there is a practical limit of events per user because a person simply cannot handle several thousand events per work week.

Answer (score 1):

The google calendar api applies some standard quota limits on you.  Basically the number of requests that you can make.  However when you are planing on using a single user then there will be some other rules you will need to consider

Copied from [here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2905486?hl=en)

> If a user has created more than 10,000 events in his or her calendar within a short period of time, that user might lose calendar edit access.
>
> If a user creates more than 25 new calendars within a short period of time, that user's calendar might go into read-only mode.
>
> In order to prevent spamming, Google Calendar limits the number of invitations a user can send to external guests. This limit varies depending on the action, and is usually between 100-300 guests.

You can do this using a service account.  To my knowledge there is no limit to the number of events you can put in a calendar per day however as stated above there will be a limit to how many you can insert at once.

I am not aware of a more sane option than this sorry.

Comment: Thanks for the info! Unfortunately that last point worries me as at scale there will definitely be more than 300 external guests being invited :/